# How to use a Non-DB-Property of a partial class in Entity Framework for an association

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables:

```
------Product-----  
| ProductID (key)|  
| DescricptionID |
|----------------|  

---Description----------  
| DescriptionType (key)|
| DescriptionID   (key)|
| LanguageID      (key)|
| Description          |
|----------------------|
```

If i want to create a new association in the `*.edmx` File between `Products` and `Description`,  i have to specify `Dependent Properties` for every primary key in table `Description`. So i created a new Partial class for this.
For Example:

```
public partial class Product
    {
        public int DescriptionType
        {
            get { return 1; }

            set { this.DescriptionType = 1; }
        }

        public string LanguageID
        {
            get { return "EN"; }

            set { this.LanguageID = "EN"; }
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is following: how is it possible to see this new properties in my `*.edmx` File to select those as `Dependent Properties` in a new Association between these two tables.
I know that the Database is not correctly designed, but there is no possibility to change this. So is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Your property setters have unbounded recursion and will blow up with a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score -1):

you can't create and association with a partial class in that way.

you could create an association in the EDMX editor.

you can try also to use EF code first and use DbSet on partial class but I never tried it

(maybe is a stupid question...but if you need that relation why don't you add it on DB)

Comment: Because, like i already mentioned, i am not allowed to change the Database. There are dozens of other programs connecting to the same database

Comment: sorry didn't read the last 2 rows.

so the only solution is to edit the EDMX to create the association.

the EDMX is not the DB so you can create associations that will resolved by EF to query the DB with joins or others.

If you can't modify the EDMX I don't think you can have the opportunity to have an association that keep tracks of changes and do the work for you to load data.